# Which class has higher priority when there are two or more classes in a <div>?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two classes in a `div` like in the example below

```css
.class1 {
      background-color: blue;
      border: solid black;
    }

.class2 {
      background-color: red;
      border: solid black;

    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="class1 class2">
    This is red
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="class2 class1">
    This should have been blue but its red
  </div>
</div>
```

There doesn't seem to be any rule regarding which class takes the precedence.

Why both the boxes has a red background in the output?

Comment: The one which is defined later in your CSS file.

Comment: Two selectors of equal precedence are applied in the order the browser reads them from the stylesheet(s).

Answer (score 1):

There are certain rules CSS bases on to apply conflicting styles.

In your case, the **last class** to be interpreted by the browser (`class2` in the first `<div>` and `class1` on the second) is the one being applied.

There are some exceptions to this rule, based on certain use cases. You can read more about CSS specificity [by clicking here](https://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/).

Answer (score 1):

i think is in which one you defined later in css file and if you use !important. You can also see this
[Is it possible to give one CSS class priority over another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671551/is-it-possible-to-give-one-css-class-priority-over-another)