# Change class priority

Tags: html, css

There is a situation that I need to change the class priority. For example:

```css
.one {
  color: green;
}

.comment {
  color: gray;
}

.red {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="one two red">Content</div>
<div class="comment two red">Content</div>
```

At the moment, `.red` `color` is applied. Is it possible to force `.comment.red` to get the `color` from `.comment`?

Note: The `.comment` `color` is unknown (comes from changeable themes).

Comment: The cascade is working against you. The selector that comes last is the one that takes priority

Comment: Plus! Important is working overtime.

Comment: @Paulie_D Without `!important`, the `.red` class wouldn't apply. :(

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51382588/8620333 ... use `not()` selector to increase specificity

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right.. I completely forgot about `:not()` ..doh

Comment: and here is a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28299817/8620333 (was searching for this one in particular)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use multiple classes to make it more specific. Also, we know that `.comment.red` needs to have min two classes. So I feel this is allowed:

```css
.one {
  color: green;
}

.comment.comment {
  color: gray;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one two red">Content</div>
<div class="comment two red">Content</div>
```

But please get rid of `!important`.

The `.comment`'s rule, instead of it being like this:

[image: img]

We can make it like this:

[image: img]

**More Explanation**

Modern browsers compute the style contexts using the rule tree. If multiple rules have the same weight, origin and specificity, the one written lower down in the stylesheet is considered and wins.

When there's only one selector here:

```
.class1 {}
```

The weight of the above rule is `0010` as per CSS specificity. The same way, if there are two classes:

```
.class1.class2 {}
.class1.class1 {}
```

Note that in the second line, I have written twice the same class. Both will be computed to `0020`, which is higher than the first one, in spite of the "unknown" class, we have two classes in the rule now.

This is the same trick I used in the above example to make the theming easier.

Comment: Can you explain the use of `.comment.comment` here

Comment: @j08691 Let me do this. I gave a pictorial explanation. I'll write in words now.

Comment: @j08691 `.comment.comment` matches the comment class twice, which doubles the specificity of the CSS. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wkz3d2ro/

Comment: @j08691 I have just added the explanation. Can you please check it out?

Comment: @David I have just added the explanation in words. Can you please check it out and let me know if it's alright or should anything be changed?

Comment: @David yes, I'm aware. I just wanted Preveen to add that to his answer since many people, especially beginners with CSS, don't understand that

Comment: Thanks @j08691.  Done it.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thank you but the color of `.comment` is changeable & unknown.

Comment: @erosman That's alright and I understand. Just use `.comment.comment` in your rule. You don't need to mention the second class. Oh and you can use `:not(.comment)` as well for the `.red`. Do you want me to add this to the answer?